# Scipy minimize SLSQP: Exit Message 3

Tags: python, scipy, constraints, nonlinear-optimization, scipy-optimize-minimize

I want to solve a multivariable optimization with inequality constraints using the scipy minimize() methode with SLSQP:

min a: f(a):
g (a) <= SIGMA

While my smaller model with the vector {a} of size 6 performs well for the function optimizeFullProfiles(), using a bigger model with size 476 resulting into the following exit message:

```
 More than 3*n iterations in LSQ subproblem (Exit mode 3)
        Current function value: 1543.3839071145048
        Iterations: 1
        Function evaluations: 268
        Gradient evaluations: 1
```

My code looks like the following:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as op

SIGMA = 0.2 * (10 ** 6)
Y_MOD = 210. * (10 ** 6)
RHO = 7.850
GRAVITY_ACC = 9.81
A_MIN = 0.05 ** 2
A_MAX = 0.25 ** 2


def w(x, adj, a):
   return GRAVITY_ACC * RHO * np.sqrt(np.sum((x[adj[:, 1]] -  x[adj[:, 0]]) ** 2, axis=1)) * a


def f(x, adj, a):
   return np.sum(w(x, adj, a))


def g(x, adj, a, s, pw, pl):
   nk = len(x)
   ne = len(adj)
   dof = nk * 3
   dir_vec = x[adj[:, 1], :] - x[adj[:, 0], :]
   lengths = np.sqrt(np.sum(dir_vec ** 2, axis=1))
   stiff = Y_MOD * (a / lengths)
   fw = 0.5 * w(x, adj, a)
   cosines = dir_vec / lengths[:, None]
   Ks = np.zeros((dof, dof), dtype=np.float32)
   K_mats = np.empty((ne, 6, 6), dtype=np.float32)
   pg = np.zeros((dof,), dtype=np.float32)
   T_mats = np.empty((ne, 2, 6), dtype=np.float32)
   for e in range(ne):
      k_mat = np.array([[-stiff[e], stiff[e]],
                      [stiff[e], -stiff[e]]])
      cx, cy, cz = cosines[e]
      T_mats[e] = np.array([
         [cx, cy, cz, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, cx, cy, cz]])
      K_mats[e] = T_mats[e].T @ k_mat @ T_mats[e]
      i, j = adj[e]
      for h, x in [(0, i * 3), (3, j * 3)]:
         for k, y in [(0, i * 3), (3, j * 3)]:
            Ks[x: x + 3, y:y + 3] += K_mats[e, h:h + 3, k:k + 3]
      pg[i + 2] += fw[i]
      pg[j + 2] += fw[j]
   p = (pg + pw.flatten() + pl.flatten())
   vec_mask = np.logical_not(s).flatten()
   d = np.zeros(dof, dtype=np.float32)
   d[vec_mask] = np.linalg.solve(Ks[vec_mask, :][:, vec_mask], p[vec_mask])
   tensions = np.empty(ne, dtype=np.float32)
   b = np.array([1, -1], dtype=np.float32)
   for e in range(ne):
      i, j = adj[e] * 3
      tensions[e] = (Y_MOD / lengths[e]) * (b @ T_mats[e] @ d[[i, i + 1, i + 2, j, j + 1, j + 2]])
return np.abs(tensions)


def optimizeFullProfiles(x, adj, x0, s, pw, pl):
   nlc = op.NonlinearConstraint(
      fun=lambda a: g(x, adj, a, s, pw, pl),
      lb=0.,
      ub=SIGMA)
   bounds = op.Bounds(A_MIN, A_MAX)
   res = op.minimize(fun=lambda a: f(x, adj, a),
                  x0=x0,
                  method='slsqp',
                  bounds=bounds,
                  constraints=[nlc],
                  tol=1e-6,
                  options={'disp': True, 'maxiter': 1000})
```

I can't figure out how to solve the error/exit message for my bigger model or which may causes this error message.

My Input for my small model is:

```
x = np.array([[0.  0.  0. ],
              [2.  0.  0. ],
              [2.  1.  0. ],
              [0.  0.9 0. ],
              [0.6 0.5 0.9]], dtype=np.float32)
adj = np.array([[0 4],
                [1 4],
                [2 4],
                [3 4],
                [1 2],
                [1 3]], dtype=int)
x0 = np.array([0.0625, 0.0625, 0.0625, 0.0625, 0.0625, 0.0625], dtype=np.float32)
s = np.array([[1 1 1],
              [0 0 1],
              [1 1 1],
              [1 1 1],
              [0 0 0]], dtype=int)
pw = np.array([[0. 0. 0.],
               [0. 0. 0.],
               [0. 0. 0.],
               [0. 0. 0.],
               [0. 0. 0.]], dtype=np.float32)
pl = np.array([[  0.   0.   0.],
               [  0.   0.   0.],
               [  0.   0.   0.],
               [  0.   0.   0.],
               [  0.   0. 500.]], dtype=np.float32)
```